# Improve bibliography layout in bookdown gitbook (using zotero)

Tags: r-markdown, bookdown, bibtex, gitbook

I am using bookdown to write a paper, and the zotero bibtex plug in to reference. When I knit, the bibliography is automatically added from my `references.bib`file. The YAML in my index is:

```
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
output: 
 bookdown::gitbook: default
documentclass: book
bibliography: references.bib 
csl: african-online-scientific-information-systems-harvard.csl
link-citations: yes
```

When I knit, it puts my bibliography at the end, which is great. However I'm not sure how to format the bibliography, at the moment it is just a block of text, I'd like a little more stylish formatting, say an indent on the second line of a specific reference.

Thanks

Comment: Please try other ```.csl``` files (https://www.zotero.org/styles/).

Comment: Hi, it makes no difference sadly. If I knit to htmlbook not gitbook it formats nicely, but I would like git book.

Comment: Hi, I see your point. Did you try something like this in your YAML: ```biblio-style: apalike```?

Comment: unfortunately that does not work

Comment: You need to remove the ```csl``` to try the ```biblio-style```.

Comment: Still no...should I download the `biblio-style`